# Can a program be coded which searches written solutions for math problems in a specific database?

Tags: javascript, math, web, web-applications, vs-web-application-project

I want to make a project for helping students to find answers to specific problems. Assume that we have a student book full of 100 math questions. I will write the questions and their solutions and create a database for that.

Is it possible for students to find the exact solution to their question by the help of a program if they write the question as an input into a web page?

Comment: Any kind of searching is definitely possible to code.

Comment: You are essentially talking about designing StackExchange. That's what our "mark as dupe" process does. Note that we have a *very* deep database of questions and answers, but it still takes human assistance to interpret free text and identify similar questions. The "Chinese menu problem" is still intractable. Maybe in a few years.

Comment: thanks for contribution